# Selector vs this in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any reason to use an ID vs "this" in the following examples:

```
$("#firstname").click(function() {
    $("#firstname").val("changed");
});
```

vs:

```
$("#firstname").click(function() {
    $(this).val("changed");
});
```

Outcome is the same either way.

Comment: The first case is redundant. `this` references the element which is triggering the click event.

Comment: In your example the end result is the same because IDs must be unique. But what happens if you change the ID to a class?

Comment: @EricMartinez: Why add as a comment?

Comment: This might be relevant (although is a little old) https://remysharp.com/2007/04/12/jquerys-this-demystified. And I rather to comment than answering, don't ask me why.

Comment: @EricMartinez: I won't ask you why because that's just one word and SO doesn't allow it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One reason to use `this` rather than the `id` is *performance*.

When you enter the click handler, `this` already exists and is set.

Therefore, I imagine it is much faster to create a jQuery object with `this` rather than invoking *sizzle*, the selector engine, to find that element by id and create the jQuery object

Another reason for choosing `this` is *semantics*. Semantically, `this` is easier to read in context when I enter the click handler. This is because I already know that the handler is for `#firstname`. However, if I see an *id* selector, I have to double check and make sure both the handler selector and the `id` selector are one and the same.

Comment: sizzle comes with jQuery?

Comment: @4thSpace, yes, sizzle is the selector engine used by jquery

Comment: Not only performance-wise, `$("#firstname")` might not even return the same set of elements as `$(this)`.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫, yes, depending on if new closures are made within the handler, `this` can change

Answer (score 5):

The idea is that if you change `firstname` above, you won't have to change it again in the second block. Eg:

```
$("#my-new-name").click(function() {
  // "this" remains the same.
  $(this).val("changed");
});
```

Also, performance-wise, `jQuery` will not need to parse the string and run through its selector engine, and instead `this` is a raw DOMElement that it can quickly detect its type and get on its way.

Answer (score 1):

And use  `this` the jQuery no need to do the selection job.
So `this` will be fast than selector

Answer (score 0):

ID can change (why you would is another matter)

consider:

```
$("#firstname").click(function() {
    $("#firstname").val("changed");
})[0].id="somethingElse";
```

vs

```
$("#firstname").click(function() {
    $(this).val("changed");
})[0].id="somethingElse";
```